# Interstitial ad is displayed with delay

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

I use google-play-services 8.1.0 (but it was tested on 7.8.0 as well). I create AdMob interstitial with this code:

```
_interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
_interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_admob));
_interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        Logger.log("onAdClosed");
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }

    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Logger.log("onAdFailedToLoad");
    }

    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        Logger.log("onAdLeftApplication");
    }

    public void onAdOpened() {
        Logger.log("onAdOpened");
    }

    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Logger.log("onAdLoaded");
    }
});
requestNewInterstitial();
```

After some user actions I call

```
if (_interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        _interstitialAd.show();
        return;
    }
```

But it takes some time before ad is shown. I've added some log messages and they show that ad is loaded onAdLoaded is called.

I measured delay before ad display and each time it's different. On Nexus 5 (marshmallow) it's from 100ms, which is good to 1500ms which is not good, but comfortable. But on other devices such Nexus 7 (2012) and Nexus 10 it's varies from 4s, to even 6s which is awful.

Also I got issue which messed up my fragments lifecycle. And I had to change fragments pop from backstack and this helps (I don't remove fragments before ads show but do this after onAdClosed), but this steps doesn't remove delay before ad display.

All this steps were done on 8.3.0 as well

Can anybody helps me to remove this delay?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this with some ads this week. It seems they are serving a new type of interstitial that is causing this delay, because it never happened before. I temporarily disabled text and image ads (because video ads seem to work well) until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't quantify what *delay* you are experiencing. So it is very hard to answer this question. But if the ad has already been downloaded before you call `show()` then the only delay will be rendering, which is impacted by the hardware you run on and the other processing that you are doing at the time.

Comment: It sounds like you have a complicated view that is probably impacting your measurements. Suggest you create a very simple Activity with an AdView and record new stats. This will probably also lead you to the problem with your view.